# Is pressure invariant under Lorentz transformations?

Tags: pressure, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In an article from the [reference](http://fisica.ciencias.uchile.cl/~gonzalo/cursos/termo_II-05/seminarios/AJP_Callen-relativistic-thermo71.pdf) there are following words (page 2):
"...pressure P is a Lorentz invariant... the result follows from standart properties of the relativistic stress-energy tensor...".

What properties are used by the authors of an article?

For example, I used the expression for stress-energy tensor of an isotropic body:
$$
T_{\alpha \beta} = (\varepsilon + p)\frac{v_{\alpha }v_{\beta}}{c^{2}} - g_{\alpha \beta }p.
$$
If pressure is determined as a 3-trace of this tensor, it's obviously that it isn't Lorentz invariant.

Comment: I don;t really understand your question, but isn't the trace of a tensor an invariant ?

Comment: 4-trace is invariant, but 3-trace is not invariant.

Answer (score 1):

I think the pressure here is "defined" by the expression for the stress-energy tensor you wrote down, or equivalently, by
$$
p \equiv \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{v_{\alpha}v_{\beta}}{c^{2}}T^{\alpha\beta}-T^{\alpha}\!{}_{\alpha}\right).
$$
My guess is that you probably would have been happier if the author had called this quantity "the pressure in the (locally) comoving frame".

Comment: So, you write about scalar $p$ which is a pressure ($T_{ii}$ component) in a case of rest frame?

Comment: @PhysiXxx Right, with a caveat that the rest frame is only defined locally because the velocity of the fluid is in general dependent on position and time.